# How to extract a pic from json with js and show in html tag

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet

Here is my json:

`{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { **"pic": "/logo2.png",** "nombre": "T2V", "x": -4.45497, "y": 36.692029, "field_8": null, "field_9": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4.45497, 36.692029 ] } },`

And this is the part of code that try to extract the pic in relative path but it doesn't work:

```
var info = L.control();
info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};
info.update = function (props) {
    // console.log(props);
    this._div.innerHTML = ''
    +(props? '<b><center style="color:#838383; margin-top:10px;">'+props.nombre+'</center></b>': '')
    +(props? '<br><b><center style="color:#838383">'+props.web+'</center></b>': '');
    +(props? '<br><img src="'+props.pic+'"style="width:40px;height:40px;">': '');
    this._div.innerHTML += '<br /><img src="link.png" style="background:rgba(254,198,41,0.8); margin-left:20px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:0px">';
};
info.addTo(map);
```

Could anyone help me with some example about this action?

Comment: define "doesn't work". Also, you're not passing any parameters to `update`

Comment: Your JSON has `**"pic` it's not really JSON (nor is the entire thing JSON) but I assume you wanted to highlight that thing and this is only a partial JSON string?  Please clarify. You may wish to put the 'map` in there and edit to a proper JSON string OR a JavaScript object parsed from JSON perhaps.

Comment: Yes, it is a partial of my json. I have not put the whole json because it is very large.

Comment: The others props are updated when i clicked in a point (props.nombre and props.web) but the image of a pic is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can create a variable for the img element and then set the attribute "src" to point the relative or absolute path of your json Object.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src', json.properties.pic);
```

And then insert the element into the container element you wish:

```
document.getElementById('img-container').appendChild(img);
```

Comment: the problem is in the twelve line of code (+(props? '<br><img src="'+props.pic+'"style="width:40px;height:40px;">': '');). i extract the pic with props.pic but it doesn't show in the html (in the map).

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly unclear how to wish to use this but this will process your parsed array (assumption it IS an array - I added another element just to illustrate)

```js
var pictures = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pic": "/logo2.png",
      "nombre": "T2V",
      "x": -4.45497,
      "y": 36.692029,
      "field_8": null,
      "field_9": null
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-4.45497, 36.692029]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "pic": "/logo3.png",
      "nombre": "T3V",
      "x": -5.45497,
      "y": 35.692029,
      "field_8": null,
      "field_9": null
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-4.45497, 35.692029]
    }
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
  var prop = pictures[i].properties
  console.log(prop.pic,"at:",prop.x,prop.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am trying another way (see the twelve line of code) extracting with props.pic and adding to html. The point is that i can extract the "nombre" and "web" fields, but not the pic.

Comment: Is it that you cannot extract it or that the image does not show up?  As your JSON sets it has the image in the root of your site (very unusual).  Is that the issue?

Comment: the image does not show up, maybe. how could i check if the image was extracted?  should the image go somewhere else? thanks Mark

Comment: It sort of depends on your routing, for example in many you see a Content folder and inside that an images folder - so it is \content\images
Those would be static image files like .gif, .png etc. that can be cached by the browser.  If you are putting those in the root, you might have to set the root folder up to allow them to be read.  Put that in browser manually and see if it shows up.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Schultheiss! I have put the images inside a folder and it worked.